# THeaderControl, how to show CheckBoxes with VCL styles on

Tags: delphi, vcl-styles, delphi-10.4-sydney

Using THeaderControl and setting CheckBoxes for the sections works fine until I turn VCL styles on. Is there a fix for this glitch? Delphi 10.4

[image]
[image]

```
object HeaderControl1: THeaderControl
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Width = 481
  Height = 25
  Sections = <
    item
      Alignment = taCenter
      CheckBox = True
      Checked = True
      FixedWidth = True
      ImageIndex = 31
      Text = 'Status'
      Width = 150
    end
    item
      CheckBox = True
      FixedWidth = True
      ImageIndex = 4
      Text = 'Type'
      Width = 100
    end>
  CheckBoxes = True
  DoubleBuffered = True
  ParentDoubleBuffered = False
end
```

Comment: VCL styles has undergone many changes. Delphi version may be relevant

Comment: Added, 10.4 Sydney

Comment: Looking at the THeaderStyleHook implementation I think they forgot to draw the checkbox.

Comment: [File a bug report](https://quality.embarcadero.com).

Comment: Sent https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-30421